# What is the best way to split a sentence for a keyword extraction task?

Tags: nlp, stanford-nlp, text-mining, opennlp

I'm doing a keyword extraction using TD-IDF on a large number of documents. Currenly I'm splitting each sentence based on n-gram. More particularly I'm using tri-gram. However, this is not the best way to split each sentence into ints constituting keywords. For example a noun phrase like 'triple heart bypass' may not always get detected as one term.

The other alternative to chunk each sentence into its constituting elements look to be part of speech tagging and [chunking](https://opennlp.apache.org/documentation/1.6.0/manual/opennlp.html#tools.chunker) in [Open NLP](https://opennlp.apache.org/). In this approach phrase like 'triple heart bypass' always gets extracted as a whole but the downside is in TF-IDF the frequency of extracted terms (phrases) dramatically drops.

Does anyone have any suggestion on either or these two approaches or have any other ideas to improve the quality of the keywords?

Answer (score 0):

What is :

1. the goal of your application ?
   --impacts the tokenization rules and defines the quality of your keywords
2. type of documents? 
   --chunking is not the same if you have forum data or news article data.

You can implement some boundary recognizer by yourself, or using a statistical model as in [openNLP](http://opennlp.sourceforge.net/models-1.5/).

The typical pipeline is that you should first tokenize as simple as possible, apply stop words removal (language-dependent), and then if needed POS tagging-based filtering (but this is a costly operation).

other options : java.text.BreakIterator,  com.ibm.icu.text.BreakIterator, [com.ibm.icu.text.RuleBasedBreakIterator](http://icu-project.org/apiref/icu4j/com/ibm/icu/text/RuleBasedBreakIterator.html)...